# UFW: Allow ping requests only for specific host

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ping

I am setuping my server and I must disable the ping requests for everyone except me and a list of hosts (aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd).

I am using the tool ufw, on ubuntu server, I read that I have to comment those lines:

## ok icmp codes

-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type source-quench -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT,

However, by doing that It will disallow everyone to ping, which is a problem because I need "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd" to have a response to is ping requests.

Can you help me to write the correct command?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on this 4 month old question. It really should be listed on a different StackExchange (such as ServerFault), but sometimes even a developer needs to configure a firewall. As it is, I'm here with an answer for you.

For your firewall rules, you'll want to accept packets from your safe IPs first and then drop the rest. Here's how I did it:

Let's assume you only want to accept one safe IP for pings and that IP address is '127.0.0.1'. Of course, this IP could be any address you want (just create more rules or define subnets for additional addresses).

**Step 1**

First thing is to check is the following in /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf

```
net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
```

...should be rewritten as with a 0 if it is not already...

```
net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all=0
```

**Step 2**

Add rules for IPv4 into /etc/ufw/before.rules

```
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -s 127.0.0.1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

**Step 3 (for IPv6 support)**

Add rules for IPv6 into /etc/ufw/before6.rules

```
-A ufw6-before-input -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type echo-request -s 127.0.0.1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

**Step 4**

Now, restart your firewall and drink a beverage of your choice.

```
service ufw restart
```

Comment: ufw-init[22459]: Bad argument `–s'

Comment: ipv6 version of localhost is ::1

Comment: I too experience a ```Bad argument `–s'```. My system = Ubuntu 18.04.3. @Zahnon - comments?

Comment: I was able to get this to work on my (above) system:

```-A ufw-before-input -s 192.168.5.0/24 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT```

Comment: This answer was additionally helpful:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14974/36362

Comment: I have fixed the dash issue (wrong char). Additionally if you have the normal icmp ACCEPT block you should replace it with these lines.